# Jquery selecionando três formulários de uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

estou tendo um problema usando Jquery, pois o mesmo está selecionando três formulários ao mesmo tempo, sendo que eles tem utilidades diferentes. Um serve para registros de novos usuários, outro para login e um que serve para que as pessoas possam enviar emails do site para mim (nodemailer).

Tudo começou quando fiz esse terceiro formulário (email), e começou a dar conflito com os demais. Digo isso pois depois que removi uma função os outros dois formulários voltaram a funcionar. O código que retirei foi esse:

```
/*  Não conheço muito jquery, mas acredito que o problema esteja aqui, pois  está selecionando todos os forms certo? mas eu queria selecionar  somente o do email */
`$('form').on('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const subject = $('#subject').val()//.trim()
const emaill = $('#emaill').val()//.trim()
const text = $('#text').val()//.trim()

const data = {
    emaill,
    subject,
    text
};
//Um dos problemas que noto é que toda vez que tento fazer login ou registra uma 
//nova conta, isso aparece no meu terminal, e não deveria.
$.post('/emaill', data, function () {
    console.log('Server received our data')

});

$('#formulario').trigger("reset");

$('#resultadoAlter').show() // Faz o alert de mensagem enviada aparecer
});
```

Comment: Está muito ampla sua pergunta, os métodos para submeter os formulários ficam tudo no mesmo arquivo ? tem como postar todos os métodos e um trecho HTML?

Comment: Pegue os formulários por id, assim será submetido apenas um formulário por vez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que provavelmente está acontecendo, ao submeter qualquer formulário é chamada a função `$('form').submit()`, pois foi passado `$('form')`, para corrigir esse problema, basta que no lugar de `form`, passe alguma `ID` ou `CLASS`, assim não haverá mais esse conflito.

Segue o exemplo a baixo:

```js
$('#formEmail').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const subject = $('#subject').val()//.trim()
    const emaill = $('#emaill').val()//.trim()
    const text = $('#text').val()//.trim()

    const data = {
        emaill,
        subject,
        text
    };
    //Um dos problemas que noto é que toda vez que tento fazer login ou registra uma 
    //nova conta, isso aparece no meu terminal, e não deveria.
    $.post('/emaill', data, function () {
        console.log('Server received our data')

    });

    $('#formEmail').trigger("reset");

    $('#resultadoAlter').show() // Faz o alert de mensagem enviada aparecer
});
```

```html
<form id="formEmail">
    <input type="text" id="subject">
    <input type="email" id="emaill">
    <input type="text" id="text">
</form>
<div id="resultadoAlter"></div>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso. 
Em um primeiro momento mudei o script para o arquivo html onde estava o formulário (pois antes estava no index principal e assim ficava com um escopo global) e funcionou. Porém fui em sua resposta e também funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O problema era o que foi dito mesmo. O seletor `$("form")` seleciona todos os formulários da página de uma vez. Colocando um `id` em cada um você irá diferenciar um do outro, porém **não** é preciso necessariamente criar um evento para cada um, tipo:

```
$("#formEmail").on("submit",...
$("#formCadastro").on("submit",...
```

Você pode usar apenas um evento para todos e tratar o que foi submetido de forma individual.

Basta em cada formulário você colocar um `id`:

```
<form id="formEmail">
   ...
</form>

<form id="formCadastro">
   ...
</form>
```

E no evento você mantém o seletor `$("form")` e pega a propriedade `.target.id` do evento para identificar qual deles foi submetido:

```
$('form').on('submit', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   let form = e.target.id; // pega o id do form submetido
   if(form == "email"){
      ... faz o AJAX referente ao email
   }else if(form == "cadastro"){
      ... faz o AJAX referente ao cadastro
   }
});
```

Veja um exemplo ilustrativo:

```js
$('form').on('submit', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   let form = e.target.id;
   if(form == "email"){
      console.log("email");
   }else if(form == "cadastro"){
      console.log("cadastro");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="email">
   Email<br>
   <button>OK</button>
</form>
<form id="cadastro">
   Cadastro<br>
   <button>OK</button>
</form>
```

Outra coisa que observei é que você deve colocar as linhas:

```
$('#formEmail').trigger("reset");
$('#resultadoAlter').show();
```

Dentro do callback do `$.post` para que sejam executadas apenas quando o AJAX tiver sido concluído:

```
$.post('/emaill', data, function () {
   console.log('Server received our data')
   $('#formEmail').trigger("reset");
   $('#resultadoAlter').show();
});
```